# Phonegap + Framework7 + backgroundGeolocation

Tags: geolocation, phonegap-build, phonegap, html-framework-7

I'm trying to use https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation with Phonegap together with a Framework7 based UI.

That plugin has a very nice example for a React app. But I can't use it with just a basic Phonegap app (plus Framework7)

I looks like the whole plugin is not available at all.
For example in the code below console.log("222") is never shown.

```
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    console.log("111")
    backgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
        desiredAccuracy: 10,
        stationaryRadius: 20,
        distanceFilter: 30,
        interval: 60000
    });

    console.log("222")

    var callbackFn = function(location) {
        console.log(location);
    };
    console.log("333")

    var failureFn = function(error) {
        console.log('BackgroundGeolocation error');
    };     
})
```

I have added the plugin with:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
```

The config.xml has the line:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="~2.3.3"/>
```

And inside the plugins folder I can see the plugin installed.

But how can I start using it?

Comment: Do you view your plugin installed with that : `console.log(window.plugins);` ?

Comment: Thanks Djiggy. No I don't see it. It only lists {"insomnia":{},"socialsharing":{}} I created a minimal Phonegap app to find the issue. But the result is the same. I set a repo for it at: https://github.com/josegrad/geotest